# How to embed URL into HTML

Tags: velo

I’m trying to link web-pages via HTML dropdown menu on wix platform. Since Wix doesn’t support external coding, I’ve to find a way how to embed URL into HTML. Unfortunately, I’m unable to figure this out. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can help me out. This is the code I’m using.

```
Search by Continent:
<select name="none"id="s">
<option selected="selected"value="one"></option>
<option value="two">Africa</option>
<option value="three">America</option>
<option value="four">Asia</option>
<option value="five">Australia</option>
<option value="six">Europe</option>
<input type=button value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage()"/>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this HTML embed code

```
<p><a href="http://google.com">Visit google</a></p>
```

[Visit google](http://google.com)

Comment: That is not quite what the OP needs, but the question got just edited so it becomes more clear what they have now and what they need. You might want to revisit this answer.